# What's the benefit of DBMS_SQL.close_cursor compared to CLOSE cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

While refactoring a PLSQL program I stumpled over aplenty of `CLOSE cursor` operations. I know about the `DBMS_SQL` package which provides the `close_cursor` procedure. But where is the difference and what's the benefit the proc in DBMS_SQL?

Comment: You'd use `dbms_sql` to close cursors opened via `dbms_sql`.  You'd use the `close` command to close explicit cursors opened via the `open` command.  You can't use one with the other (the data types are actually different...  a `dbms_sql` cursor handle is just a numeric data type not a cursor).

Comment: But is possible to translate for dbms_sql to ref cursor and vice-versa. DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER,  DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR